# UIView as Separator in UITableViewCell and Row selected color

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a TableView in my app, and I needed to change the height and the color of the Separator. Browsing here in SO helped me to figure out the solution.
So I'm basically adding a UIView in my cell and using this as a "fake" separator:

```
UIView *colorSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 53, cell.frame.size.width, 4)];
    colorSeparator.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:colorSeparator];
    [colorSeparator release];
```

But now I noticed that when the row is tapped, the selection colour applies to my fake separator. Does anyone know how could avoid it? Thx in advice for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restore color of your separator in `setSelected:animated:` and `setHighlighted:animated:` methods of UITableViewCell.

```
// just edited your function, it was missing a square bracket
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UIColor *c = [[colorSeparator.backgroundColor retain] autorelease];
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    colorSeparator.backgroundColor = c;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UIColor *c = [[colorSeparator.backgroundColor retain] autorelease];
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    colorSeparator.backgroundColor = c;
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot! So you mean I should sublcass UITableViewCell and override this two methods?

Comment: Yes, you should subclass UITableViewCell, override this methods and return objects of your new class from UITableView delegate method.